# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud' while importing automl in GAE Standard?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-automl

I get a-

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

My environment details are standard environment, python 3.8, F1

I am using automl and everything works fine in my local machine with google-cloud-automl conda package which I include in the requirements file. What is going wrong? I vaguely have a guess that it may be due to a difference between second generation vs first generation of GAE instances. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: Similar previous questions/answers involve one of (a) package issue at a local server (b) importing deprecated google-cloud package

Comment: How do you import your `google.cloud`?

Comment: I use 
    from google.cloud import automl
in my program. It runs fine on the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52924123/8753991), if you are using a `conda` to install your packages:

> There is no way to install packages on App Engine Standard with an installer other than `pip`.

You should use `pip` to install your packages in App Engine Standard to avoid unexpected errors. I did replicate importing `automl` in App Engine Standard and there's no problem at all. If you want to still use `conda` You can consider [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) that supports [Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes) which allows you to define your preferred environments.

Comment: For now, I have switched to flex. Thanks.