# How to deploy on Google App Engine with anaconda environment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, plotly-dash

I'm new to GCP tools and deploying and working with envs so please bear with me!

I created a Plotly Dash app which runs fantastically locally. The app relies on several dependencies not available through `pip`, ie. Pylucene, which I had to build and install myself.

I understand and have succesfully deployed a dummy Dash app with simple `pip` requirements, which works as expected since it reads the requirements.txt file and installs basic packages needed.

How would I deploy my more complex app with non-`pip` packages? I already have a conda environment which I am currently using. Can I somehow upload this to Google?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing packages on Google App Engine using Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922820/installing-packages-on-google-app-engine-using-anaconda)

Comment: If you search app engine and anaconda you'll find lot's of good info here.

Comment: Hi @Ice Lemons , have you already checked the given thread above?

Comment: Yes I've checked that thread, the only answer simply says it's not possible. So how would I go about deploying something like this on GCP? I find it extremely hard to believe that a service like this is limited to pip packages, but if that's the case then...

Comment: Then you can go with Cloud Run and use a container which gives you more flexibility